# ibis ImpalaTable to pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, impala, kudu, ibis

In my case, I need to load impala data to spark(pyspark).
Because I want to use `FPGrowth` of spark mllib.

Data is in kudu and it was made by impala. Connecting to directly kudu on spark was rejected by a relevant department. And I also failed connecting with impala jdbc made by cloudera.
So my last choice is

1. Load data with ibis (https://github.com/ibis-project/ibis)
2. Convert `ImpalaTable` to spark's `Dataframe`

But I couldn't find a way.
Do I think wrong?

Comment: Hi. Have you check this way => https://medium.com/@sciencecommitter/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-kudu-tables-in-pyspark-via-impala-c4334b98cf05 But you first need to make an access to kudu throught impala.

Comment: @airliquide, I've seen that post, and I retried it. And I finally found I had a firewall problem on data nodes. So that's why I couldn't query to kudu tables (timeout error) while I could get infos. Thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Previously, [this way](https://medium.com/@sciencecommitter/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-kudu-tables-in-pyspark-via-impala-c4334b98cf05) was not worked for me.
I could get schema of tables, but I couldn't query because of timeout.

And I finally found a problem.
My problem caused by firewall.
I opened ports of only master nodes, but **I needed to open ports of data nodes.**
And now everything is fine.